# How to make ClickOnce target .NET 2.0 and not 3, 3.5 or 4

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I've got a simple [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application - it only targets .NET 2.0, but in the prerequisites I've got to select .NET 3.5 as a minimum prerequisite, whereas I really want to have .NET 2.0 as a prerequisite.

I'm in Visual Studio 2010... What do I do?

Comment: If you have a prerequisite of .NET 3.5 then that includes the ability to run .NET 2.0 programs. Why are you running a non-supported version of Visual Studio exactly?  I am going to guess that ClickOnce was introduce after .NET 2.0 was released this doesn't meant you cannot force the application to only use C# 2.0 syntax.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, that was supposed to be Visual studio 2010! Brain not connecting today.  It's not a major problem if it installs .net 3.5, but it only targets .net 2, so I don't see why it needs to ask for 3.5 - particularly if someone's already got 2.0 installed, it's something extra and uneccessary to install.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwade/archive/2008/08/29/what-s-new-in-visuall-studio-2008-sp1-clickonce-tooling.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project, select *Properties* and then *Application*. Make sure the target framework is [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework 2.0

(Repeat the operation if your solution contains more than one project.)

Then select *Publish*. Click on the prerequisites button and make sure that if the setup program creation is selected, on .NET Framework 2.0 is checked.

That should do it.

Comment: That's the problem - .net Frameword 2.0 doesn't appear in the prerequisites list to check...

Comment: This option is only to build a prerequisites setup, are your projects configured to use .net 2? (1st step)

Comment: They are yes - how do I build a prerequisites setup?

Comment: I just had a look at the setup projects - there's no .net 2 in the prerequisites for them either...

Comment: @Paul - Visual Studio 2010 by default does not contain the .NET Framework Installer like Visual Studio 2008 did. You have to modify the product.xml file within the Bootstrapper. You also if your going to include the installer within your installer modify the PublicKey to the 3.5 package to the correct value. This is a known issue with 2008 and 2010.  The setup launch conditions should also be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the .NET 2.0 bootstrapper package from Visual Studio 2008's folders to Visual Studio 2010's folders and it will magically show up and work.